# iOS: CoreData save and search NSEntityDescription or kSetAttrDescription

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

Im new to Objective-C and CoreData and want to learn it and im trying in Xcode 5, im trying to make this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Core_Data_Tutorial).

I have followed it with some other CoreData table name, but i get some errors with my "ViewController.m" and dont know what to changes, i can see it recomment to changes "NSEntityDescription" to "kSetAttrDescription" but dont know if thats right or wrong to do, hope someone can tell mewhat to do - so i know it next time.

**Error issues**

[image: ViewController.m error]

**Error Descriptions**
[image: Error description]

My ViewController.m code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Save data as CoreData, to CoreData Table "Kunder" field "navn", "adresse", "alder" from textfield _name.text, _adress.text, _age.text.
- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newContact;
    newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Kunder" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newContact setValue: _name.text forKey:@"navn"];
    [newContact setValue: _adress.text forKey:@"adresse"];
    [newContact setValue: _age.text forKey:@"alder"];
    //if textfield empty, then error else save and show label message "Kunde Gemt".
    _name.text = @"";
    _adress.text = @"";
    _age.text = @"";
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    _status.text = @"Kunde Gemt";
}

//Find-search for user by name.
- (IBAction)findKunde:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Kunder" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *pred =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(navn = %@)", _name.text];
    [request setPredicate:pred];
    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
    //if no user then error, else take name match and get "adresse" and "alder" from CoreData and show it in the text fields _adress.text and _age.text and show matche count in status label.
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if ([objects count] == 0) {
        _status.text = @"Ingen fundet";
    } else {
        matches = objects[0];
        _adress.text = [matches valueForKey:@"adresse"];
        _age.text = [matches valueForKey:@"alder"];
        _status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lu antal fundet", (unsigned long)[objects count]];
    }
}
@end
```

My ViewController.h page (no error)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h" 

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *adress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *age;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)findKunde:(id)sender;

@end
```

My AppDelegate.m file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
....
@end
```

**UPDATE**

When adding text to the fields and hit save, i don get a "Save ok" message it jump to xcode and show me this.
[image: error]

Comment: Are you sure that `<CoreData/CoreData.h>` is imported in your precompiled header file? - And please copy/past your `saveData:` method as *text* into the question, not as (clipped) screenshot.

Comment: Hi Martin. hmm i have added the saveData: under "My ViewController.m code." !

Comment: Sorry, I had overlooked that. What about `<CoreData/CoreData.h>`?

Comment: np ;-) I have no CoreData.h file, the CoreData.xcdatamodeld have i called Model.xcdatamodeld, but cant finde any info/text in my files about Model, if i then need to import <Model/Model.h> in what file do i do that, cant see that in the tutorial ?

Comment: Ahh so its a little like code behind in asp.net where i also import the SQL and so on, here i just do it in the Prefix.pch file, I only get to error/issues now about "ARC Semantic Issue - No Visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'managedObjectContext'

Comment: Then you have to add `@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;` to AppDelegate.h. - If you create a new project in Xcode with the "Master Detail Application" template and select "Use Core Data" then you get a sample application that shows all the necessary imports, declarations etc.

Comment: ahh thats why, i started a "Single Page" project. Thx alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is seems that you forgot to import `<CoreData/CoreData.h>`. 
You can add the import to your precompiled header (...-Prefix.pch) file
which would look similar to this:

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>         // <-- Add this !!
#endif
```

You might also have to add the "CoreData.framework" to the "Link Binary With Libraries"
section of the targets "Build Phases".

Comment: Have added the Framework to and have run a test, i can fine write data/text, but when i hit save, i get the added image under UPDATE, what does that mean ?

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen: That means that *somewhere* in your application an uncaught exception was thrown. - You can add an "Exception Breakpoint" in Xcode, that might help to locate the problem. Apart from that, try to set breakpoints on your code and single-step to isolate the problem.

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen: As your initial question was about *compiler errors* (which are hopefully solved now) I would suggest that you start a new question about the *runtime exceptions*, if necessary.